# OpenGL send me a Stack Underflow error when i am trying to use shaders (Java)

Tags: java, opengl, shader, lwjgl

I am developping a game with lwjgl 3 in java and it was working fine but when i want to use shaders, OpenGL send a STACK_UNDERFLOW error (1284).

I am using 3 buffers: vertex buffer, color buffer, index buffer;

My old code:

```
private int vbo;
private int cbo;
private int ibo;
private FloatBuffer buffer;
private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;
private IntBuffer indexBuffer;

private IcoSphere sphere;
int radius = 200;

@Override
public void init() {
    sphere = new IcoSphere(9, radius);
    sphere.generate();
    generateBuffer();
}

private void generateBuffer() {
    buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(sphere.getVertexCount() * 3);
    colorBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(sphere.getFacesCount() * 4 * 4);
    indexBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(sphere.getFacesCount());

    Random r = new Random();
    OpenSimplexNoise noise = new OpenSimplexNoise();

    ArrayList<Vector3f> vertex = sphere.getVertex();
    float[] v = new float[vertex.size() * 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < vertex.size(); i++) {
        vertex.get(i).normalize();
        vertex.get(i).mul(sphere.getRadius() + (float) noise.eval(
                vertex.get(i).x * 8,
                vertex.get(i).y * 8,
                vertex.get(i).z * 8
            ) * 12);
        v[i * 3 + 0] = vertex.get(i).x;
        v[i * 3 + 1] = vertex.get(i).y;
        v[i * 3 + 2] = vertex.get(i).z;
    }
    buffer.put(sphere.getVertexArray());

    indexBuffer.put(sphere.getIndexArray());

    for (int i = 0; i < sphere.getFacesCount(); i++) {
        colorBuffer.put(new float[] {
                r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1,
                r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1,
                r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1
        });
    }

    buffer.flip();
    colorBuffer.flip();
    indexBuffer.flip();

    createBuffer();
}

private void createBuffer() {
    vbo = glGenBuffers();
    cbo = glGenBuffers();
    ibo = glGenBuffers();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

@Override
public void update() {

}

@Override
public void render() {
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sphere.getFacesCount() * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}
```

My new code after adding shaders:

`GlUtils.glCall(() -> ..);` is for catching opengl errors.

```
private int vbo;
private int cbo;
private int ibo;
private FloatBuffer buffer;
private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;
private IntBuffer indexBuffer;

private IcoSphere sphere;
int radius = 200;

@Override
public void init() {
    sphere = new IcoSphere(9, radius);
    sphere.generate();
    generateBuffer();
}

private void generateBuffer() {
    buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(sphere.getVertexCount() * 3);
    colorBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(sphere.getFacesCount() * 4 * 4);
    indexBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(sphere.getFacesCount());

    Random r = new Random();
    OpenSimplexNoise noise = new OpenSimplexNoise();

    ArrayList<Vector3f> vertex = sphere.getVertex();
    float[] v = new float[vertex.size() * 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < vertex.size(); i++) {
        vertex.get(i).normalize();
        vertex.get(i).mul(sphere.getRadius() + (float) noise.eval(
                vertex.get(i).x * 8,
                vertex.get(i).y * 8,
                vertex.get(i).z * 8
            ) * 12);
        v[i * 3 + 0] = vertex.get(i).x;
        v[i * 3 + 1] = vertex.get(i).y;
        v[i * 3 + 2] = vertex.get(i).z;
    }
    buffer.put(sphere.getVertexArray());

    indexBuffer.put(sphere.getIndexArray());

    for (int i = 0; i < sphere.getFacesCount(); i++) {
        colorBuffer.put(new float[] {
                r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1,
                r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1,
                r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1
        });
    }

    buffer.flip();
    colorBuffer.flip();
    indexBuffer.flip();

    createBuffer();
}

private void createBuffer() {

    vbo = glGenBuffers();
    cbo = glGenBuffers();
    ibo = glGenBuffers();

    GlUtils.glCall(() -> glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo));
    GlUtils.glCall(() -> glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW));
    GlUtils.glCall(() -> glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0));

    GlUtils.glCall(() -> glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo));
    GlUtils.glCall(() -> glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW));
    GlUtils.glCall(() -> glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0));

    GlUtils.glCall(() -> glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo));
    GlUtils.glCall(() -> glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW));

    GlUtils.glCall(() -> glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0));
    GlUtils.glCall(() -> glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0));

}

@Override
public void update() {

}

@Override
public void render() {
    Shader.MAIN.bind();

    GlUtils.glCall(() -> glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0));

    GlUtils.glCall(() -> glEnableVertexAttribArray(0));
    GlUtils.glCall(() -> glEnableVertexAttribArray(1));


    GlUtils.glCall(() -> glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexBuffer));

    GlUtils.glCall(() -> glDisableVertexAttribArray(0));
    GlUtils.glCall(() -> glDisableVertexAttribArray(1));

    Shader.MAIN.unbind();
}
```

My shaders:

Frag

```c
#version 410

out vec4 vertColor;

void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vertColor;
}
```

Vert

```c
#version 410

layout (location=0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a shader program, then you can draw the mesh the same way as you did it before, by using the client side capabilities.
All you have to do is to use `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttribPointer` instead of `glEnableClientState`, `glVertexPointer` and `glColorPointer`:

Create the buffers:

```java
vbo = glGenBuffers();
cbo = glGenBuffers();
ibo = glGenBuffers();

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Draw the mesh

```java
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sphere.getFacesCount() * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

What you actually do is to use default [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) (0) for the specification. Note, the default VAO (0) is just valid in a compatibility profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context).

---

That can be improved by using a named [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). Note, you have to use a named VAO in a core profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context):

```java
private int vao;
```

```java
vao = glGenVertexArrays();
vbo = glGenBuffers();
cbo = glGenBuffers();
ibo = glGenBuffers();

glBindVertexArray(vao);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

The vertex array specification is stated in the vertex array object. Thus there is no need  of`glDisableVertexAttribArray`.
Furthermore the [Index buffers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) (`GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`) is stated in the VAO, too. `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` would break the binding.

Now it is sufficient to bind the VAO when the mesh is drawn:

```java
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sphere.getFacesCount() * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

---

You have 2 color attributes, the vertex coordinate and the color. This 2 attributes are the input to the [Vertex Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader). The vertex coordinate is used to set `gl_Position`. The color has to be passed to the [Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader). It is an output of the vertex shader and an input to the fragment shader. In the fragment shader the color is written to the output `fragColor`. The output of the fragment shader is written to the frambuffer:

Vertex Shader:

```c
layout (location=0) in vec3 position;
layout (location=1) in vec4 color;

out vec4 vertColor;

void main()
{
    vertColor = color;
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```c
#version 410

in vec4 vertColor;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = vertColor;
}
```

Comment: It work but the all is white, there is no colors and i must disable my shader because there doesn't work can you help me ?

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: @Swiiz I've extended the answer. See the last section.

Comment: It still does not work, when I put the shader nothing is displayed and when I do not put it I have the forms but everything is white.

Comment: @Swiiz I've no idea what's wrong in your code. Anyway I can just see the snippets in the question, the issue seems to be else where.